# Hanling various encoding in emails, Python

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, imap

I have a problem with email with various encoder and i do't know how to handle/encode/decode all incoming mails properly, because......i don't have any clue how they encode their mails. Can you try my code and suggest a solution for normal handling? Because some mails i can handle, but then my script crashes on other mails.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import sys
import email
import imaplib
from datetime import datetime
from getpass import getpass

detach_dir = 'C:\PyDir\\'
u_line = '\n____________________________\n'


def login_data():
    mailboxes = ['@yandex.ru', "@gmail.com", "@mail.ru"]
    servers = ['yandex.ru', 'gmail.com', 'mail.ru']
    srv = ''

    login = input("Enter your email: ")
    for lgt in range(len(mailboxes)):
        if mailboxes[lgt] in login:
            srv = servers[lgt]
            break
    return login, srv

def address_parser(address):
    if "<" in address:
        return ''.join(address.split("<")[1:]).replace(">","")
    else:
        return address 

def subj_checker(subj):
    if None or "" in subj:
        return "<No theme>"
    else:
        return subj


def mailbox_proc(mail):

    mail.select("INBOX")
    rv, mdata = mail.search(None, "ALL")#(None, "FROM", login)
    if rv != 'OK':
        print("No message found")
        return

    for i in mdata[0].split():
        rv, mdata = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)')
        if rv != 'OK':
            print("Error fetching mail")
            return

        msg = email.message_from_bytes(mdata[0][1])
        email_from = str(email.header.make_header(
            email.header.decode_header(msg['From'])))
        email_to = str(email.header.make_header(
            email.header.decode_header(msg['To'])))
        subj = str(email.header.make_header(
            email.header.decode_header(msg['Subject'])))
        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(msg['Date'])
        if date_tuple:
            local_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            local_message_date = "%s" % (str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))

        try:
            print('From: %s\nTo: %s\nDate: %s\nSubject: %s\n%s' % (address_parser(email_from), 
                                                                   address_parser(email_to),
                                                                   local_message_date,
                                                                   subj,
                                                                   u_line))
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            print('From: %s\nTo: %s\nDate: %s\n<UNABLE TO ENCODE HEADER>\n%s' % (address_parser(email_from),
                                                                                 address_parser(email_to),
                                                                                 local_message_date,
                                                                                 u_line))

        for part in msg.walk():
            outname = "email_" + i.decode("utf-8")

            if part.get_content_maintype() == "multipart":
                continue
            if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain" or "text/html":
                if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                    body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                    f = outname + '.txt'
                    out = open(f, 'w')
                    out.write('From: %s\nTo: %s\nDate: %s\nSubject: %s\n\nBody: \n\n%s' % (address_parser(email_from),
                                                                                           address_parser(email_to),
                                                                                           local_message_date,
                                                                                           subj,
                                                                                           body.decode('utf-8')))
                    out.close()

            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is not None:
                fname = part.get_filename() or part.get_param('filename')
                f = open(outname + '_' + fname, 'wb')
                f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
                f.close()


def main():
    print("Enter email: " + login_data()[0])

    M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.' + login_data()[1], 993)
    try:
        rv, data = M.login(login_data()[0], getpass("Enter password: "))
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
        print("\nimaplib.IMAP4.error: Authorization failed")
        sys.exit(1)
    print("\n")
    print(rv, data)

    if rv == 'OK':
        print("Processing mailbox...\n")
        mailbox_proc(M)
        M.close()
    else:
        print("Error: Cannot open mailbox ", rv)

    M.logout()


try:
    main()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
# finally:
#     input("Press any key.....")
```

Comment: Crashes how?  Please provide an exact error message and stack trace.

Comment: Right now in one mailbox i have this problem: File "D:\genesi5\Универ\7 сем\ММиВА\Лабы\L4\main.py", line 89, in mailbox_proc
    body.decode('utf-8')))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 6: invalid start byte

Comment: Well, for one, your body may not be in UTF-8.  Did you look at the Content-Type header for a character set?

Comment: @Max it's utf-8, but subject looks like that: =?UTF-8?Q?=D0=92=D1=8B=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=BA=D0=B0_=D0=BF=D0=BE_?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=88=D0=B8=D0=BC_=D0=BE=D0=BF=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B0?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=D1=86=D0=B8=D1=8F=D0=BC_=D0=B7=D0=B0_=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=D0=BB=D0=B5=D0=B4=D0=BD=D0=B8=D0=B9?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=BC=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=8F=D1=86?=

Comment: Your subject is in UTF-8.  Your body isn't, or it's invalid.  Your stack trace is on body.decode().